# Writing a keyboard driver that accepts input from code

Tags: c++, filter, driver

The ultimate goal of this project is to send low level input (so that it looks like it is coming from the keyboard) to my windows machine.

I know C++, Python, and Java. Though I would love to do this in python, C++ will probably be the only option.

I have been searching around the internet and have found something called a Keyboard Filter Driver that can inject keystrokes into the keyboard stream by adding an extra layer to the driver. Is this the best way to accomplish my goal? If yes, where could I find some material to help me code it?

**Note: Windows Function SendInput() is not an option for me**

Comment: Could you explain why `SendInput` or `keybd_event` are "not an option for you"? I used this functions and have very good results. You have a problem which you try to solve with writing of a keyboar driver or a filter, but if you descibes here your original problem, one could suggest your a better way to a solution.

Comment: I need the same thing! Please post the solution!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181034/sendkeys-not-working-3rd-party-software-blocks-it-is-there-any-keyboard-drive#comment13065947_10181034comments may only be edited for 5 minutes(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: Found more info here: Simulate keystroke http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=139268. But unfortunately it is not the final solution!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download DDK or WDK and look at kbfiltr sample. You can't use Python or Java. Drivers are typically written in C. If you have no driver development background it will be not so easy (you need to read a lot of docs to understand what you are actually doing).

Good luck!